# Send stdout + stderr to file, AND send stderr + arbitrary status messages to console

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I dug through probably 20 questions across SO looking for a solution to this problem with no luck. It seems like a common task.

I have the following requirements for a bash script:

1. Send `stdout` to `log.out`, NOT to console
2. Send `stderr` to `log.out` AND to console
3. Send arbitrary status messages to console (and to `log.out`?)

Currently I am attempting the following to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/bash

> log.out

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>log.out 2>&1

# Test
echo "status goes to console" >&3
echo "stderr goes to file + console" >&2
echo "stdout goes to file"
```

My understanding of this code is roughly...

1. Backup stdout to FD 3, and stderr to FD 4
2. Reset them when the script exits (maybe unnecessary?)
3. Send stdout to log.out, and send stderr there too

This works perfectly except that errors are not displayed to the console.

So, I thought, I'll just cat `/dev/stderr` to `&3` in a separate bg process, and added this line under the 2nd `exec`:

```
cat /dev/stderr >&3 &
```

I don't understand why, but, this also sends stdout to &3, so my console reads:

```
echoes goes to console
stderr goes to file + console
stdout goes to file
```

I've tried probably 50 combinations without success. After much reading I am leaning towards needing a (custom?) C program or similar to achieve this, which seems kind of crazy to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

## Thanks!

Hey thanks to @charles-duffy's comments and answers I was able to make a very small modification to my existing script that achieved the general idea of what I'm looking for:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>log.out 2> >(tee /dev/tty >&1)
```

The downside is that messages do appear out-of-order in the log file.

Comment: You're going to lose synchronization between writes.

Comment: As in writes to the console? Async is fine as long as the `log.out` file is in proper order.

Comment: That's the thing -- you lose the ability to guarantee order when you do this. We've got some good duplicates with an in-depth explanation of why; looking for them.

Comment: ...basically, the OS only provides a guarantee that order of writes to two FDs will result in appends being in that order when they're both `fdup()`s of each other. You can't have two FDs be duplicates of each other if they're pointing to different destinations.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of `> log.out` and then `exec >>log.out`, instead of `exec >log.out` alone? You're truncating the file and then appending to it for the course of the process either way.

Comment: At some point during my trials, each message was truncate the log, so I only saw the last message in the log. That `>>` is probably a hold-over from previous attempts. RE: link, that URL leads me to this question haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have bash 4.1 or later:

```
# make copies of orig stdout, /dev/tty, and our log file FDs
exec {orig_stdout_fd}>&1
exec {tty_fd}>/dev/tty
exec {file_fd}>log.out

# ...and set them up however you wish, using ''tee'' for anything that goes two places
exec >&$file_fd                                  # redirect stdout only to the log file
exec 2> >(tee /dev/fd/"$tty_fd" >&$file_fd)      # redirect stderr to both sinks
```

Note that writes to stderr will take longer than writes to stdout (since they're going through a FIFO), so ordering can be lost.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for the answer. So far with this, I am not seeing the arbitrary status messages in the tty. The goal is to have a (large) provision script cleanly send all the `apt-get` garbage to `log.out`, while printing pretty, high-level status messages to the console (e.g. installing xyz...) AND showing any errors to the user immediately. Ideally the log has everything (just in case).

Comment: stderr is supposed to be used for *all* "diagnostic" content (a category which includes status updates), not just errors. So directing stderr to the user means you're showing all the status you're saying you don't want too, not just error messages as such.

Comment: anyhow, it's quite common for programs to use `isatty()` to change their default log level. I'd suggest taking a close look at whether that's happening.